# Exchanging the sum and the min in double sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

I'm trying to know under which conditions the following equality holds:
$$\underset{x\in \mathbb{R^n}}{\min}{\sum _{i=1}^n}{\sum _{j\in [[1,i]]}}f_{i,j}(x)={\sum _{i=1}^n}\underset{x\in \mathbb{R^n}}{\min}{\sum _{j\in [[1,i]]}}f_{i,j}(x),$$
where $f_{i,j}$ is a linear function with respect to $x$.
I'm aware of the answers in [Minimum of a sum of positive functions is the sum of the minimums of the functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260435/minimum-of-a-sum-of-positive-functions-is-the-sum-of-the-minimums-of-the-functio)
but it seems that it cannot be applied to my case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are really only two cases to consider, for linear functions $f(x)$:

- If $f(x) = 0$ is constant, clearly its minimum is $0$;
- If $f(x)$ is not the zero constant function, then its minimum does not exist (i.e. $\inf_x f(x) = -\infty$).

Since the sum of linear functions is linear, you should be able to use the above facts to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you sir, it is clear now. What if the minimum was taken above a compact set?